# Small glitches on secondary monitor's taskbar every time it pops up

Tags: windows-10, display, multiple-monitors, taskbar

I am getting these little colored stripes across my secondary taskbar that appear for just a moment when the bar pops up and goes down. (These stripes are always the same color as my desktop wallpaper). It was difficult to take an image or even a video, (too low FPS I think) because of how quick the flicker is, so I recreated a similar effect in Photoshop [(File attached).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etJpN.png)

I have used many third party applications to modify different aspects of my computer in the past. I have uninstalled most, which leads me to think it is a glitchy remainder of some old program I've already uninstalled that is interfering with the default windows 10 taskbar.

I have tried a few things with no success, and I am willing to try any ideas that you might have. The issue is a little hard to describe, so if you need further explanations, I would be glad to provide them! :)

Comment: Is the secondary monitor connected to the same graphics system as the primary? E.g., if you're using integrated + dedicated graphics, is one on integrated and one on dedicated? Second question: have you overclocked your graphics system?

Comment: @lungj Yes, they are both connected to the same system. My GPU is the GTX 1070 FTW Edition, which I believe did come just a little overclocked.I had a GTX 760 before, just in case that information comes in handy.

Comment: Oh... there goes my hypothesis. It sounded a bit like corrupt VRAM or overclocking, but I would expect to see the symptoms on both monitors, not one, if they're both connected to the same graphics card.